DynamoDB Conditional Delete When Item Might Not Exist
I’m trying to perform a DeleteItem operation in DynamoDB with the following conditions:

If the item with a given primary key (PK) does not exist, the delete operation should succeed.

If the item exists, it should only be deleted if a certain condition (e.g., attribute B equals a specific value) is satisfied.

The entire operation must be handled in a single request (i.e., no additional queries or transactions).


Here’s the DeleteItem request I’ve been trying (example):
deleteInput := &dynamodb.DeleteItemInput{
    TableName: aws.String("YourTableName"),
    Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "PK": {S: aws.String("PrimaryKeyValue")},
    },
    ConditionExpression: aws.String("attribute_not_exists(PK) OR #status = :statusValue"),
    ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
        "#status": aws.String("Status"),
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        ":statusValue": {S: aws.String("Completed")},
    },
}

_, err := dynamodbSvc.DeleteItem(deleteInput)
if err != nil {
    if _, ok := err.(*dynamodb.ConditionalCheckFailedException); ok {
        fmt.Println("Condition check failed: PK exists but Status is not Completed.")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Delete failed: %v\n", err)
    }
} else {
    fmt.Println("Delete succeeded.")
}

This works as expected when the item exists, and the condition is either satisfied or not. However, if the item does not exist, I get a ConditionalCheckFailedException instead of the operation succeeding.
From my understanding, the attribute_not_exists(PK) condition should evaluate to true when the item does not exist, allowing the operation to proceed. But this doesn’t seem to be happening.
How can I ensure that the delete operation succeeds when the item is missing, while still applying the condition check when the item exists? Is there a limitation in how DynamoDB evaluates conditions in such scenarios?
Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I'm not certain, but you could try mapping "PK" to an expression attribute name, and then referencing the string "PK" using that?
So, change the top bit to:
deleteInput := &dynamodb.DeleteItemInput{
    TableName: aws.String("YourTableName"),
    Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "PK": {S: aws.String("PrimaryKeyValue")},
    },
    ConditionExpression: aws.String("attribute_not_exists(#part_key) OR #status = :statusValue"),
    ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
        "#status": aws.String("Status"),
        "#part_key": aws.String("PK"),
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        ":statusValue": {S: aws.String("Completed")},
    },
}

Might work.

Sorry, I missed that while changing my code to the example. I've tried with expression attribute names given, but it also fails.

Oh. That's too bad. I'm getting quite stuck in to dynamodb stuff for a project I'm doing, at the moment. If I stumble upon anything I will post again. Seems like there's gotta be a way, because your use-case is hardly a niche one.
